# Classes CSS (Optional) - how do I reference this in php?

Tags: menus, links, walker

I've read an infinite (yes there seems to be more than I care to read) same articles on how to apply a classes to the anchor not the link element using `nav_menu_link_attributes` and a walker.

However, none of them implement the custom class option in the menu to be utilized on the anchor.  Seems like a nice feature to have to allow the user to add their own class, however, what if I want to apply that class to an specific isolated element in the theme?

[image]

I have tried but not seen where it documents what this data value is returned in?  How can I reference this optional piece of data?

My project uses the anchor class attribute to scroll to the section of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access those classes like this:

```
// where 'Top' is the menu name, slug or ID. But not menu location.
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'Top' );

foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
  $menu_classes = $menu_item->classes;
  print_r( $menu_classes ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding that it is the first key defined in `$items->classes` thus used a description walker to check if there was not an empty `$items->classes[0]`.

```
! empty( $item->classes[0] )
    and $attributes .= ' class="'   . esc_attr( $item->classes[0]        ) .'"';
```

For those of you who wish to use this in your own project please use the code below.

```
class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
/**
 * Start the element output.
 *
 * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
 * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
 * @param  array|object $args    Additional strings. Actually always an 
                                 instance of stdClass. But this is WordPress.
 * @return void
 */
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 )
{
    $classes     = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;

    $class_names = join(
        ' '
    ,   apply_filters(
            'nav_menu_css_class'
        ,   array_filter( $classes ), $item
        )
    );

    ! empty ( $class_names )
        and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

    $output .= "<li id='menu-item-$item->ID' $class_names>";

    $attributes  = '';

    ! empty( $item->attr_title )
        and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
    ! empty( $item->target )
        and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
    ! empty( $item->xfn )
        and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
    ! empty( $item->url )
        and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';

//if the custom classes field is NOT empty dump it into the link attributes. 
    ! empty( $item->classes[0] )
        and $attributes .= ' class="'   . esc_attr( $item->classes[0]        ) .'"';

    // insert description for top level elements only
    // you may change this
    $description = ( ! empty ( $item->description ) and 0 == $depth )
        ? '<small class="nav_desc">' . esc_attr( $item->description ) . '</small>' : '';

    $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

    $item_output = $args->before
        . "<a $attributes>"
        . $args->link_before
        . $title
        . '</a> '
        . $args->link_after
        . $description
        . $args->after;

    // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
    $output .= apply_filters(
        'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
    ,   $item_output
    ,   $item
    ,   $depth
    ,   $args
    );
}
}
```

Let me know if this was helpful for you!